# Why Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 2) instead of initializing to empty array?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to learn Javascript by reading the source code of Fabric.js.

In file `util/lang_array.js` there is a method that looks like this:

```
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    function invoke(array, method) {
        var args = slice.call(arguments, 2), result = [ ];

        for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
            result[i] = args.length ? array[i][method].apply(array[i], args) : array[i][method].call(array[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I don't understand the statement `var args = slice.call(arguments, 2)`. The particular part that puzzles me is passing `2` as the second argument (considering `arguments` being `[array, method]` then `arguments[2]` should be `null`). I looked up the JS reference and came to the conclusion that it basically initializes args to an empty array.

Then why not simply `var args = []`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is there to pick up any *extra* arguments supplied to the function.

Those extra arguments are then passed to the specified method in the `.apply` call.

NB:  JS does *not* check the formal parameters of functions.  Omitted parameters will be `undefined`, and extra parameters will be (mostly) ignored, but available through the `arguments` pseudo-array.

I'm unsure why the code bothers checking `args.length` to see whether to call `.apply` or `.call` - it looks like premature optimisation.

Comment: Regarding apply vs call, I'm not sure about latest versions of engines but argument creation has always been costly. I remember implementing similar optimization in Prototype.js back in the days. It's a small addition that saves some cycles. This is also one of the methods that could be called thousands of times per second (when redrawing canvas with complex shapes consisting of thousands of paths).

Answer (score 0):

Just because the function has two parameters doesn't mean that more can't be passed in. In Javascript you can pass in as many parameters as you want and access them through `arguments`.

Also, it seems like this is a generic invoke function that is meant to work on any method (the second function argument) call, so different functions can have different number of arguments (or none).